# Programmatically/Dynamically import modules in Julia

Tags: julia

I was wondering if there was a way to programmatically or dynamically import a set of modules into Julia? For example, if I have a list of files that conform to some naming convention that are present at startup that I can grab using something like:

```
module_files = filter(r"^mod[0-9][0-9].jl$", readdir())
```

which might return a list of files `["mod00.jl", "mod02.jl", "mod05.jl"]`, is there a way to then import each of the modules in those files. This would be equivalent to having:

```
import mod00
import mod02
import mod05
```

in the code if I knew that those modules were available when I wrote the code. Or maybe there is some other approach to doing this that is better. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I attempted to do this via a macro, but with no luck. For example:

```
macro import_mod(modn)
    quote
        import $modn
    end
end

function test_mimport()
    module_files = filter(r"^mod[0-9][0-9].jl$", readdir())
    println(module_files)
    for modname in factor_files
        modn = modname[1:end-3]
        println(modn)
        @import_mod modn
    end
end
```

When I run this, I get `ERROR: syntax: invalid "import" statement`. I tried various escaping strategies but all failed similarly.

Comment: Because `import` is a keyword, not a function, I'd say you need to define a [macro](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/) for that.

Comment: @Jubobs I played around with doing this via a macro for a bit, but Julia seems to not like the `import` statement in the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function version of `import X` is `require("X")`, so you should be able to do:

```
function test_mimport()
    module_files = filter(r"^mod[0-9][0-9].jl$", readdir())
    println(module_files)
    for modname in factor_files
        modn = modname[1:end-3]
        println(modn)
        require(modn)
    end
end
```

Then, assuming each of these defined a module of the same name, you can collect them into an array:

```
modules = Module[]
...
if isdefined(Main, symbol(modn))
    push!(modules, getfield(Main, symbol(modn))
else
    warn("importing $modn did not defined a module")
end
...
return modules
```

Comment: Is the documentation of the equivalence between `import X` and `require("X")`? The `include` vs `require` vs `import` vs `using` is one of the more confusing aspects of Julia that I've run across.

Comment: If you find this documentation is not enough to be helpful, please consider opening an issue or editing the documentation yourself (open the relevant file in your web browser on GitHub and click the little pencil icon).

Comment: @tholy I had seen the `require` docs and looked at the modules section as well, but it was unclear if `import` just added some syntactic sugar on top of `require` or if there were additional side effects of calling one or the other. On the google group Isaiah suggested `eval(Expr(:import, symbol(modn)))`, which explicitly call `import`.

Comment: I also know that there has been a long recent discussion on julia-user about abusing `include` (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/julia-users/5UBon35puRs), but it would be great to have a faq that explicitly laid out when one would use `require` vs `include` vs `import` and why, both in the context of files that contain modules or not.

Comment: @tholy I find it pretty difficult to edit something I don't fully  understand and I don't think opening an issue will help in this case. I think we all know we need more examples in the manual (not just about metaprogramming), but I know the devs like the manual to be short, so perhaps another official document more explicit and extensive is needed. And only the ones with more expertise and understanding will be able to shed light into this, I'll keep using trial and error until then and while it may be fun and enlightening it's definitely not very productive.

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE:** Please refer to user1712368's (Jameson Nash, Julia dev) answer, this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/bLDuSI1MkVA) at the *julia-users* mailing list and this entry of the Julia [manual](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/style-guide/#don-t-overuse-macros), to know about why this is **not** the correct answer.

This is how a multiple import expression looks like, using Julia version 0.3.4:

```python
julia> parse("import Foo, Bar")
:($(Expr(:toplevel, :($(Expr(:import, :Foo))), :($(Expr(:import, :Bar))))))

julia> dump(ans)
Expr 
  head: Symbol toplevel
  args: Array(Any,(2,))
    1: Expr 
      head: Symbol import
      args: Array(Any,(1,))
        1: Symbol Foo
      typ: Any
    2: Expr 
      head: Symbol import
      args: Array(Any,(1,))
        1: Symbol Bar
      typ: Any
  typ: Any
```

Here is a macro which does this programmatically, it takes a `modules` argument that could be a `:call` or `:vcat` `Expr` or a `Symbol`, which has to evaluate to a `Vector{Symbol}`:

```python
julia> macro dynamic_import(modules)
           (modules = eval(modules))::Vector{Symbol}
           ex = Expr(:toplevel)
           for m in modules
               push!(ex.args, Expr(:import, m))
           end
           return ex
       end
```

You could also generalize this line:

```python
module_files = filter(r"^mod[0-9][0-9].jl$", readdir())
```

By abstracting it into a function that takes a `Regex` and a `String` directory path as arguments and returns a `Vector{Symbol}`:

```python
julia> function needed_modules(rx::Regex, dir::String=".")
           module_files = filter(rx, readdir(dir))
           module_syms = map(m -> symbol(split(m, '.')[1]), module_files)
       end
needed_modules (generic function with 2 methods)
```

So you may use it like this:

```python
julia> @dynamic_import [:Mod01, :Mod02]    # :vcat expression

julia> rx = r"^Mod[0-9][0-9].jl$";

julia> @dynamic_import needed_modules(rx)    # :call expression

julia> modules = needed_modules(rx)
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :Mod01
 :Mod02

julia> @dynamic_import modules    # Symbol
```

<strike>Finally you could wrap it all into a [module](https://gist.github.com/Ismael-VC/cb7e31e9f39fa757c8b8) so you may use `using DynamicImport`:</strike>

**Note:** currently I get this when trying to run the same examples from a module:

```python
julia> using DynamicImport

julia> @dynamic_import [:mod01, :mod02]

julia> rx = r"^mod[0-9][0-9].jl$";

julia> @dynamic_import needed_modules(rx)
ERROR: rx not defined

julia> modules = needed_modules(rx)
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :mod01
 :mod02

julia> @dynamic_import modules
ERROR: modules not defined
```

But it works fine If I define the objects inside the REPL, I guess this is an issue involving hygiene, which is something I'm not experienced with, so I'll ask at the julia-users mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not thrilled with this solution, but it seems to work. Basically I dynamically create a temporary file contains the import statements that I then `include` it. So:

```
function test_mimport()
    module_files = filter(r"^mod[0-9][0-9].jl$", readdir())
    path, f = mktemp()
    for modname in module_files
        modn = splitext(modname)[1]
        write(f, "import $modn\n")
    end

    close(f)
    include(path)
    rm(path)

end
```

I would be curious to know if there is a more idiomatic strategy since I'm new to Julia and just wadding through its capabilities.

**Edit**

The strategy of setting up a temporary file is likely unnecessary since Julia also provides an [`include_string`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/#Base.include_string) method.

On the Julia-user list, @Isaiah also [suggests](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/UKKmr1w376o/3M66AZJEULsJ) using `eval(Expr(:import, symbol(modn)))`